# upload image files from dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

Kindly help on how to upload selected images from dropzone to a specific directory. Here's my code:

```
    <div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone">
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Upload</button>
    </div>
    <script>
            Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
                url:"upload.php",
                uploadMultiple: true,
                maxFilesize: 2,
                maxFiles : 3,
                autoDiscover:false,
                acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.jpeg",
                previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
                autoProcessQueue : false,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,       
                init:function(){
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    $("#submitbtn").on('click',function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
                }

           }
</script>
```

I can drag photos in the dropzone, but it's not appearing in my subdirectory. Here's code on upload.php:

```
session_start();

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$upload_dir = './upload_photos';

if (!empty($_FILES)) { 
     $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__).$ds.$upload_dir.$ds;
     $targetFile = $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 

     move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

}
```

What can I do?